# What is possible in Java not in C# and vice versa

Tags: c#, java

In our real life Java and C# both has a significant effect. Personally I love Java because of its complexity also I have experience in C# too. I want to know, from desktop application to robotics, web application to machine learning what are the fields which are possible in Java but not currently available in C# and vice versa. Thank you.

Comment: If you love complexity, I propably don't want to see - let alone maintain - your code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think there are any good answers to this question, and it is highly subjective. Pretty much both languages are very capable. Voted to close.

Comment: both are general purpose languages, not specific to any field. Voting to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given both languages are Turing complete, anything you can do in one language you can do in the other.

Comment: Lol'd at both the answer and comment =D I knew this Question was going to spawn something funny so I came back =P

Comment: @delnan: I was going to put something about different libraries for different languages making different tasks -easier-, but didn't really feel like it. :-)